# Recursion using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT and currently working on the recursive function on an input XML to convert to a target XML using xslt.

1. Input XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<referenced>
<name>XYZ</name>
<LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <reference>
        <name>MC</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    </reference>
    <reference>
        <name>MC1</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    </reference>
    <reference>
        <name>List</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            <reference>
                <name>entList</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </reference>
            <reference>
                <name>ist</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </reference>
            <reference>
                <name>WumentList</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
                    <reference>
                        <name>WumentList</name>
                        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
                    </reference>
                    <reference>
                        <name>WumentList</name>
                        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
                    </reference>
            </reference>
    </reference>
        <reference>
        <name>entList</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            <reference>
                <name>entList</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </reference>
            <reference>
                <name>ist</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </reference>
            <reference>
                <name>WumentList</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </reference>
    </reference>
</referenced>
```

2. Target XML I want to achieve:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<children>
<name>XYZ</name>
<LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <children>
        <name>MC</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>MC1</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>DocumentList</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            <children>
                <name>entList</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>ist</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>WumentList</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
                    <children>
                        <name>WumentList</name>
                        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
                    </children>
                    <children>
                        <name>WumentList</name>
                        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
                    </children>
            </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>st</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            <children>
                <name>entList</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>ist</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>WumentList</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </children>
    </children>
</children>
```

3. XSLT Function which I have written:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="reference"/>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="reference[reference]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="reference"/>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="reference">
        <children>
            <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            </name>
            <LOCK_STATUS>
            <xsl:value-of select="LOCK_STATUS" />
            </LOCK_STATUS>
        </children>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Somehow I am not able to achieve the target XML with the xslt which I have written.

Hi Tim,

Appreciate your help on this . Trying to understand the code spinet you provided and the tutorials i went over internet to get more understanding :)

No in my case i do not have to rename referenced to reference .

How would the xslt change if the Expected Output xml should appear like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nodeInfo>
<name>XYZ</name>
<LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <children>
        <name>MC</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>MC1</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>DocumentList</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            <children>
                <name>entList</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>ist</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>WumentList</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
                    <children>
                        <name>WumentList</name>
                        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
                    </children>
                    <children>
                        <name>WumentList</name>
                        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
                    </children>
            </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>st</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            <children>
                <name>entList</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>ist</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>WumentList</name>
                <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
            </children>
    </children>
</nodeInfo>
```

Comment: I've amended my answer, but it would have been clearly if you had not added a second input XML to your question, but rather amended the original input XML to what you wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem you have is that your root element is named `referenced`, but in your first template it is looking for a root element of `reference`

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="reference"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

The `/` symbol matches the top-level document node, which is the parent of the single root element of your XML (`referenced` in your case).

You also don't need the second template that matches `reference[reference]` as this will skip over any `reference` element with a child `reference` element, which is not what you want.

But if you want recursion, you simply need to add an `xsl:apply-templates` to your template that matches `reference`

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="referenced">
        <nodeInfo>
            <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            </name>
            <LOCK_STATUS>
            <xsl:value-of select="LOCK_STATUS" />
            </LOCK_STATUS>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="reference" />
        </nodeInfo>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="reference">
        <children>
            <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            </name>
            <LOCK_STATUS>
            <xsl:value-of select="LOCK_STATUS" />
            </LOCK_STATUS>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="reference" />
        </children>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Better still, make use of the [identity template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which cuts down on the work you have to do (as it looks like all you are trying to do is rename `referenced` to `nodeInfo`, and `reference` to `children`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="referenced">
        <nodeInfo>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </nodeInfo>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="reference">
        <children>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </children>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Does the identity template help in copying all the contents under referenced to nodeInfo and reference to children provided their structure is same ?

Comment: Yes. The identity template is used to copy across all nodes and attributes that you don't want to change. In this case you are replacing `reference` by `children` but keeping all the descendant nodes the same, so the identity template will handle those for you.

Comment: But at my end it isnt happening . The input xml has been modified a bit where reference has some additional descendent nodes now . After xslt is been applied ( identity template ) , the same not seen in output xml in children . Can i repost the input xml ?

Comment: This answer really relates to the XML you have shown. If you have since changed the XML then it's probably best you ask a new question, to avoid this question becoming a bit unmanageable. Thanks!

Comment: @ Tim C - Perfect . I have posted as a different Question in different post . Hoping to see your advice there as well . Thank you.